# FullCalendar v6 fails in Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, fullcalendar

I'm updating my project to Angular 14. Apparently, FullCalendar v6 is the unique compatible with Angular 14. So, I followed this [steps](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v6/angular) to update the library.

This was good and everything looks like working. However, when I run the test with the [jest library](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started), the result is the below:

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      15 | import { CreateBookingComponent } from '../create-booking/create-booking.component';
      16 | import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/core';
    > 17 | import { defineFullCalendarElement, FullCalendarElement } from '@fullcalendar/web-component';
         | ^
      18 |
      19 | // NOTE: These imports are needed for the calendar to work and have to be the last ones
      20 | import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1422:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/vdom.cjs.js:3:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.cjs.js:10:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fullcalendar/web-component/main.cjs.js:10:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/my-bookings-calendar/my-bookings-calendar.component.ts:17:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/app.module.ts:44:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/edit-reservation/edit-reservation.component.spec.ts:9:1)
```

This is the jest configuration in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^config$": "<rootDir>/extra-webpack-config.js"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ]
  }
```

And this is the `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        EmptyRouteComponent,
        CreateBookingComponent,
        MyBookingsTableComponent,
        EditReservationComponent,
        MyBookingsCalendarComponent,
        ViewSelectedTabComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        CommonModule,
        ThemeModule,
        DropdownModule,
        I18NextModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ButtonModule,
        TableModule,
        CalendarModule,
        ConfirmDialogModule,
        FormsModule,
        DynamicDialogModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CheckboxModule,
        InputTextModule,
        InputNumberModule,
        DialogModule,
        OverlayPanelModule,
        MultiSelectModule
    ],
    providers: [
        I18N_PROVIDERS,
        ConfirmationService,
        DialogService,
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es' },
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
```

I'm a bit lost because I don't find anything on Internet and I have never worked with web components until now. So, Can anyone help me with this error?

Thank you in advance,

- Angular version: 14
- Jest version: 29.2.1
- "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.0.0-beta.1"
- "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.0.0-beta.1",
- "@fullcalendar/interaction": "6.0.0-beta.1",
- "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "6.0.0-beta.1",
- "@fullcalendar/web-component": "^6.0.0-beta.1",

***Proved solutions:***

Solution 1:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "/node_modules/(?!@fullcalendar/*).+\\.[t|j]sx?$"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `transformIgnorePatterns`. Because full calendar might have js files that are not compatible with a transpiler

```
"jest": {
    ...,
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!your-module-name)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have added ```"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!@fullcalendar/*).+\\.[t|j]sx?$"
    ]``` and it doesn't still working

Answer (score 0):

I found [this workaround](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7113):

Simply add this to jest.config.js

```
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: [] // don't load "browser" field
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).